# Is there a method to obtain the incoming call number with swift?

Tags: swift2

I want to write an app that blocks unwanted calls and am wondering if there is a library or framework I can work with swift. I know there's CT telephony but I read that someone says you can't obtain the number of the caller ?

Thanks for the help guys !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to intercept and parse incoming calls via an app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21737541/how-to-intercept-and-parse-incoming-calls-via-an-app)

Comment: Without jailbreaking, you can't. You may find some private APIs to do this, but your app will be ineligible for the App Store